Permission Denied When Accessing Symbol Link in /proc/<pid>
I am encountering a "Permission denied" error when trying to access the symbol link of an nginx worker process which running under the adg user.
Similar question: Owner can't read /proc/$pid/io, but a little different. My problem is symbol links cannot be accessed, and the output of ls -l contains "Permission denied" error(from stderr) and normal result(from stdout). The specific output is as follows:

Print the information of nginx worker process and its fd:

root# ps -fp 2728114
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
adg      2728114 2723696  0 21:11 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process

root# stat /proc/2728114/fd/0
  File: /proc/2728114/fd/0 -> /dev/null
  Size: 64              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
Device: 0,21    Inode: 204114580   Links: 1
Access: (0700/lrwx------)  Uid: (  948/     adg)   Gid: (  948/     adg)


Execute ls -l with adg user and root user:

root# sudo -uadg ls -l /proc/2728114/fd/0
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/2728114/fd/0': Permission denied
lrwx------ 1 adg adg 64 Aug 20 21:12 /proc/2728114/fd/0

root# sudo -uadg -gadg /bin/sh -c 'ls -l /proc/2728114/fd/0'
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/2728114/fd/0': Permission denied
lrwx------ 1 adg adg 64 Aug 20 21:12 /proc/2728114/fd/0

root# ls -l /proc/2728114/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 adg adg 64 Aug 20 21:12 /proc/2728114/fd/0 -> /dev/null


Check user and group:

root# grep adg /etc/passwd
adg:x:948:948::/home/adg:/sbin/nologin

root# id -nu 948; id -ng 948
adg
adg


Check the status of selinux

root# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

root user can access the fd normally, but the owner cannot, could anyone help me troubleshoot this?

If a process has ever run with elevated privileges, then a lot of files under /proc/<pid> are made accessible to root only. This is still the case even if the process abandons all elevated privileges. This is a security measure: the process may have access to extra information that its user should not have access to.
For example, the process may have opened a file in a directory that the user cannot read, and kept it open while abandoning elevated privileges. The user should not gain access to the file's name, since that would violate the lack of read permission on the directory.
I guess that on your system, nginx starts with elevated privileges — presumably CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE to allow it to bind a port lower than 1024. Since nginx started with elevated privileges, only root can access most of the process's introspection interfaces, such as /proc/<pid>/fd listings.
(You could argue that if the only privilege ever granted to the program was CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE, then it can't have gained any extra privileges on the filesystem, so it's safe to expose its open file paths. But keeping track of that would be a lot of extra work with subtle security rules for very little benefit, so the kernel doesn't try to be that sophisticated.)

Thanks so much for your help. You are absolutely right, the nginx ELF file had been indeed set CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE. After execuing setcap -r nginx, I can successfully access all files under /proc/<ngx-pid>/. Maybe I need to go to learn the procfs in depth.
